# set icon on a Fast Overlay in OSMDROID

Tags: android, overlay, android-mapview, osmdroid

I have inserted a map in my android app using osmdroid, over which I lay out ~10K pins. I want each pin to have an icon (same icon for all pins). I know how to do it for a single icon with Marker class.

I am using SimpleFastPointOverlay in order to optimize drawing so many pins on the map. I could not figure out how to set an icon to the theme of the points.

Relevant code:

```
    // wrap points in a theme
    SimplePointTheme pointThm = new SimplePointTheme(points, true);

    // >>>>>> THIS I WANT TO REPLACE WITH AN ICON
    Paint textStyle = new Paint();
    textStyle.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    textStyle.setColor(Color.parseColor("#0000ff"));
    textStyle.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
    textStyle.setTextSize(24);

    SimpleFastPointOverlayOptions opts = SimpleFastPointOverlayOptions.getDefaultStyle()
            .setAlgorithm(SimpleFastPointOverlayOptions.RenderingAlgorithm.MEDIUM_OPTIMIZATION)
            .setRadius(7).setIsClickable(true).setCellSize(15).setTextStyle(textStyle);

    // create the overlay with the theme
    final SimpleFastPointOverlay fastOverlay = new SimpleFastPointOverlay(pointThm, opts);
    mapView.getOverlays().add(fastOverlay);
```

How can I set the icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's unfortunately not possible with [SimpleFastPointOverlay](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/master/osmdroid-android/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/views/overlay/simplefastpoint/SimpleFastPointOverlay.java). It supports only simple shapes: circle or rectangle.

I see following two options, if you really need icons:

1. **Preferred**: Try [ItemizedIconOverlay](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/master/osmdroid-android/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/views/overlay/ItemizedIconOverlay.java) with [OverlayItem](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/master/osmdroid-android/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/views/overlay/OverlayItem.java) instances. `OverlayItem` is more lightweight than `Marker`. The `ItemizedIconOverlay` class also have a default marker (drawable) parameter in its constructor, so you don't need to set drawable to each `OverlayItem` instance.
2. Create a custom subclass of the `SimpleFastPointOverlay` class and override its `drawPointAt` method and implement rendering as you wish. Remember to minimize allocations in order to keep good performance. Keep in mind that this is an attempt to bend the class to have other than intended behavior. It's harder to implement correctly and there will be sideeffects, e.g. broken click handling, as revealed in comments.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I subclassed SimpleFastPointOverlay. Two issues, 1. icons are only shown over map after a tap/click on the map. 2. My onClickListener is not always called, only sometimes. What parameters is this related to? I thought only of SimpleFastPointOverlayOptions radius and cellSize. Any idea about these issues?

Comment: @KerenMeron I am not sure about the first problem (was it introduced by the modification?) But the second - clicking - is a problem and doesn't have simple solution. There is [hardcoded tolereance +/- 50px in the SimpleFastPointOverlayClass](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/8cae40361945637c8866fd011ae5f301cbbc9b48/osmdroid-android/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/views/overlay/simplefastpoint/SimpleFastPointOverlay.java#L223). I suppose you should use the first solution, If you have problems with the second one.

Comment: @KerenMeron It's true, that the second option I suggested in my response (the one you chose) is more "hacky" and less proffered one. I should have stated that in my response and I will update the response to make it more clear for other readers.

Answer (score 0):

Following Josef Adamcik's answer, I subclassed SimpleFastPointOverlay. This works for displaying icons. The class implementation:

```
public class PPSimpleFastPointOverlayActivity extends SimpleFastPointOverlay {

    public PPSimpleFastPointOverlayActivity(PointAdapter pointList, SimpleFastPointOverlayOptions style) {
        super(pointList, style);
    }
    public PPSimpleFastPointOverlayActivity(PointAdapter pointList) {
        super(pointList);
    }
    protected void drawPointAt(Canvas canvas, float x, float y, boolean showLabel, String label, Paint pointStyle, Paint textStyle){
        BitmapFactory.Options opt =  new BitmapFactory.Options();
        opt.inSampleSize = 1;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(PPSession.getContainerContext().getResources(), R.drawable.logo_small, opt);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, x, y, pointStyle);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest to move the line with bitmap decoding to a constructor or use a lazily initialized field. [Something like in this gist](https://gist.github.com/josefadamcik/56823b0c23f4dd9c13d1977a02bc4dea). Your code will create new bitmap object in memory each time it renders one icon. This will have negative impact on performance.

Answer (score 0):

I have 15 000 items in a database and read only those items that are currenly visible as  ItemizedIconOverlay into a folderOverlay in a background task (AsyncTask) . When background loading is finished the folderOverlay is added to the map (and the previous-folder-overlay is removed) background loading takes about 1.5 seconds

the relevant markers where read like this:

```
        // SELECT poi.lat, poi.lon, poi.id, poi.name FROM poi
            //    WHERE poi.lat >= {latMin} AND poi.lat <= {latMax}
            //          AND poi.lon >= {lonMin} AND poi.lon <= {lonMax}
            //          AND {zoom} >= poi.zoomMin AND {zoom} <= poi.zoomMax
```

Here is the AsyncTaskDemoFragment demo for it
 https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/pull/406/commits/47be1608d737e43cc056ab099574114885cc8e05#diff-9054da2bf477910ac6c3388bf40d44f3

that unfortunaltely was removed from osmdroid sources.

See also: [osmdroid/issues/182: Performance Issue with a lot of Overlays](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/issues/182)

Answer (score 0):

This is not the answer to the whole question.

but the answer to "1. icons are only shown over map after a tap/click on the map."

I think you didn't call "mapView.invalidate()"

I had a hard time with the same issue...

but it was written in the OSMDroid official document.... haha..

https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/Markers,-Lines-and-Polygons-(Java)

(Look at the bottom 'Tips' section.)